# token setting in headers and verification in jsonwebtoken

Tags: angularjs, node.js, authentication, jwt

I am working on a web app in which i am trying to implement jwt authentication for security. I am sending the generated token to the client side and saving it in headers but when i am sending **http request** then header is showing empty on server side.

this is server side code part for **login module**.

```
           var profile = {
                name:rows[0].name,
                email:rows[0].email,
                role:rows[0].role_id
            };
            var token = jwt.sign(profile,'shhhhhhared-secret',{expiresInMinutes: 60*5 });

            res.json({
                success: true,
                user: rows[0], //userobject 
                token: token
            });
```

this is the controller part where we are setting the response in sesssionstorage.

```
dbServices.UserAuthenticate($scope.email,
                  $scope.password).then(function(response) {
                $rootScope.showLoader = false;
                if (response.data.success) {
                    var session_data = {
                        'token':response.data.token,
                        'user':{
                            'name':response.data.user.name,
                            'role':response.data.user.role_id,
                            'email':response.data.user.email
                        }
                    };
                    sessionStorage.sessionData = JSON.stringify(session_data);
                    $location.path('/');
                } else {
                    $scope.msg = 'Invalid Email or Password!'
                }
            })
```

**this is config file where i am setting headers**

```
App.factory('authInterceptor', ['$rootScope', '$q', '$window',
function($rootScope, $q, $window) {
    return {
        request: function(req) {
            req.headers = req.headers || {};
            if (sessionStorage.sessionData.token) {
                req.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.sessionData.token;
            }
            return req;
        },
        response: function(response) {
            if (response.status == 401) {
                console.log('header auth 401 login');
                $window.location = '/login';
            }

            return response || $q.when(response);
        }
    }
}
]);

App.config(function ($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');
});
```

I am not getting whats going wrong in this. Can anybody help me out.

Comment: Looks like sessionStorage is undefined....  You may need to inject it.

Answer (score 0):

You do `JSON.stringify(session_data)` when saving the token but you don't do `JSON.parse(sessionStorage.sessionData)` before reading it.

Try changing

```
if (sessionStorage.sessionData.token) {
    req.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.sessionData.token;
}
```

with

```
var session_data = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.sessionData);
if (session_data.token) {
    req.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + session_data.token;
}
```